# react-navigation space between left button and title on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation for navigate between screen.
In ios it display on center and working properly but in android it display left side and space between back button and title.

[image]

I want to remove space between back button and title on android.

**My Code**

```
class Detail extends Component {
    .
    .
    .
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
        const {state} = navigation;
        return {
            headerTitle: "title",
            headerStyle: {
                borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
                borderBottomWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',

                elevation: 0 ,
                shadowOpacity: 0,
                shadowColor: 'transparent',
                shadowRadius: 0,
                shadowOffset: {
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0
                }
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              color: 'white',
              width: width-72,
            },
            headerBackTitleStyle: {
              color: 'white',
            },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            headerBackground: (
                <LinearGradient
                    colors={[MyConstants.colorNavbarStart, MyConstants.colorNavbarEnd]}
                    style={{ flex: 1 ,padding: 0}}
                    start={{x: 0, y: 0.5}}
                    end={{x: 1, y: 0.5}} />
            ),
            headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={{padding: 8}}>
                <Image source={MyConstants.imgShareArrow} style={{height:20, width: 20}} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => {navigation.pop()}}>
              <View style={{padding: 8}}>
                <Image source={MyConstants.imgBackArrow} style={MyStyle.backButton} />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        };
    };
}
```

In above code **width** is screen width and i'm using -72 because left and right button width.
I'm also using marginLeft in minus but it cut the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Some change It's Working
Change headerTitle in above code

```
headerTitle:<Text numberOfLines={1} style={[MyStyle.appFontStyle1, {color: 'white', width: width- (Platform.OS==='ios'?72:118), fontSize: 20}]}>Title</Text>
```

Comment: I did something like that, i know its not perfect but manually added few spaces before actual text `headerTitle: <Text numberOfLines={1}>{"   " + variableContainingTitleText}</Text>`

Answer (score 13):

to remove space between back button and title you can use:

```
headerTitleContainerStyle: {
  left: 0,
},
```

Comment: Works on iOS - You've saved me! Thank you

Comment: I'm using the version `5` of the navigation library and this code moves the title to the left edge of the screen instead of the the right edge of the back button. Is it possible to position the title relative to the back button?

Comment: I'm also using `react-navigation` version 5 and this moved the title to the very left edge of the screen. But it actually did something. So that's a start. I just adjusted it to `left: 50` in order to allow for extra room for the back button and now it looks great. You'll likely want to adjust this based on your platform and if the back button is showing or not as well. I wish there was an easier way but I couldn't find one. Thanks @John!